# Can something be a premonition?

Tags: meaning

Would it be correct to say that something "serves as a premonition" or "is a premonition"? According to [Webster's dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/premonition), a premonition is

> 1: previous notice or warning : FOREWARNING
> 2: anticipation of an event without conscious reason : PRESENTIMENT

and this usage seems to fit the first definition. The examples that Webster provides, however, all reference someone *having* a premonition, not a premonition existing. This aligns with my intuitive understanding of the word, but doesn't seem to be required by that definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on whether you're writing a period piece set in the 16th to 18th centuries, or whether you're talking about present-day senses in common use.

The original meaning was that of a forewarning, but now it most often means a presentiment. The OED says:

> An advance warning, a forewarning. Originally: the action of warning in advance; an advance notification of subsequent events. Now usually: a strong feeling that something is about to happen, especially something unpleasant; a presentiment or foreboding.

The most recent citation they give of the forewarning kind is from 1869. There were lots of those for the three centuries leading up to then. After that, the newer sense shows up in the citations from then till now.

That doesn't mean you can't use it in its original sense. It's just not the usual sense people would today be expecting from it.

Comment: It's fairly common to talk of an object "offering a premonition" of something, and not much of an extension from that to saying the object is a premonition. And it's common to see artworks etc described as premonitions, which could be extended to other created objects. [Here's an theatre review](https://grocotts.ru.ac.za/2022/06/27/a-street-sign-is-a-premonition/) (a genre sometimes given to florid language) headlined "a street sign is a premonition". So I agree it might appear unusual, poetic, or metaphorical but it's not much of an extension from the normal usage.